# how to upload file on django server using javascript/jQuery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, upload

After having spent hours, I need help to match the javascript code to the django codes.

I am using the "minimal-django-file-upload-example" version django 1.8 from the git https://github.com/axelpale/minimal-django-file-upload-example.
In standalone, it works very well.

Now i try to upload file from javascript and i do not succeed to make it works.

**Javascript Code**

```
function UploadBlob(zip)
{
    var ZipFileBlob = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('data', ZipFileBlob);
    fd.append('fname', 'ZipOfImage.zip');
    fd.append('enctype','multipart/form-
    $.ajaxSetup({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/list/',
    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") }
});

$.ajax({
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
}).done(function(data) {console.log(data);});
```

}

**Django code**

in forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
```

in views.py

```
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
        newdoc.save()

        # Redirect to the document list after POST
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproject.myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        print "invalid form"
else:
    form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

# Load documents for the list page
documents = Document.objects.all()

# Render list page with the documents and the form
return render_to_response(
    'list.html',
    {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

The code run up to the request.method == 'POST'. After, i do not know if i should add field to the ajax requests  (and which ones) or if there is a more suitable form in django or do something else.

Please help!

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: you are reading my thoughts, here are they.  1) form.is_valid is always false.  2) when  i remove the condition on form.is_valid i get the http error 500. Meaning there are error in  the instructions: newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])

Comment: your 500 should throw a specific django stack trace error right?  it's hard to understand where the problem could be, I created an HTML5 file uploader and had a hard time satisfying the CSRF token among other things. I ended up having to write a lot of code to get it to work, probably not the best example, but it did work. https://github.com/chawk/django-easy-avatar/tree/master/easy_avatar

Comment: thank you, i will look at the git. What should i do to see the django stack trace error. On the console i see only 500

Comment: Chris, i looked at your code and change newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile']) into newdoc = Document(request.POST, request.FILES) like in your file.  Now i have done one more step. The error occurs at  newdoc.save(). Thank for this step. Still Error 500

Comment: if you have the django debugger turned on in the settings file and use the console to view the response from the server, it should show the standard django stack trace error pointing to where it blew up in your code..

Comment: so it is what i see on the console, error 500 at newdoc.save()